# Extracting each word from a string

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to count the number of words in a String, find the length of each word in a String and then determine the largest word in the String using only the String class. I can't use arrays. Does anyone know a way to extract each word from the string?

Comment: I do not understand how to do this without arrays. `split()` method of a `String` object was the first thought in my head. Without arrays, you will have to look for spaces (as word delimiters) and use `indexOf()` method of `String` object

Comment: Try something like String.split("\w");

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle and that would give a `String[]`. No arrays.

Comment: I saw it after, sorry. I posted an aswer using only the class String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int indexOfSpace = 0;
int nextIndexOfSpace = 0;

String sentence  = "This is a sentence";

int lastIndexOfSpace = sentence.lastIndexOf(" ");
while(indexOfSpace != lastIndexOfSpace){
    nextIndexOfSpace = sentence.indexOf(" ",indexOfSpace);  
    String word = sentence.subString(indexOfSpace,nextIndexOfSpace);
    System.out.println("Word: " + word + " Length: " + word.length());
    indexOfSpace = nextIndexOfSpace;
}

String lastWord = sentence.subString(lastIndexOfSpace);
System.out.println("Word: " + lastWord + " Length: " + lastWord.length());
```

You need to do something along the above lines. Since your question seems like a homework question, I am not going to put an effort into debugging this. This is as far as I can go into answering what seems like a homework question.

Debug it, use it.

Comment: This does seem to clearly be either a homework question or some sort of 'do you actually know basic programming theory that shouldn't be done this way in the real world' interview prescreening question.

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni Yes, it does, but I answered the question just for practice. :-D oh and look it got accepted as the answer.

Comment: Was just agreeing with you on that. His accept, my upvote are what's showing so far....

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni, it is homework, but I was merely looking for a suggestion on how to separate the strings since the professor isn't that far in. I've taken some java but I've merely done this assignment using Arrays so I keep trying to backtrack and not use Arrays. 

Little Child, thank you, this looks like it will be my best to work with.

Comment: @TravisJames Sure. Now please be courteous enough to tell me if it worked. :-D I haven't compiled it.  Let's see if I got the output right :D and gimme an upvote :D

Comment: Oh, certainly not crying foul about the homework question, just observing that unless you're teaching the most basic concepts, this is a waste of time and effort compared to using Scanner or other higher-abstraction classes designed to do just this  type of work in the basic class library.

Comment: @LittleChild It doesn't compile correctly, it loops infinitely. I'd still upvote for the help but I can't cause my rep isn't high enough. :/

Comment: Also, I think this will also have problems with `'Word___word_words__worldly_words.'` type formations as you're not accounting for nextindexofspace=indexofspace+1 and skipping it as a word.... (nope, I've never had to write character stream parsers....)

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner s= new Scanner("Put your string here");
while(s.hasNext()){
    String word= s.next();
}
```

Edit using only String:

```
String myString = "hello world how are you";
for (int i = 0,                   //start of word
     j = 0;                       //end of word
     i < myString.length();       //make sure we're in bounds
     i = j + 1) {                 //Start from where we left off plus one
                                  //to get rid of space we just found

    j = myString.indexOf(" ", i); //find the next space
    if (j == -1) {                //-1 means no more spaces so we're done
        break;
    }
    String word = myString.substring(i, j); //here is your word
}
```

Comment: It is not stated that the input is from keyboard. It could be hardcoded into the program or read from a file :)

Comment: @Little Child the scanner takes input from a string hard coded and get get it from a file too with a FileInputStream

Answer (score 2):

Use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

```
String sentence = "This is a sentence"; 
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(sentence);
String word ="";
while(t.hasMoreTokens())
{
    word = t.nextToken();
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

The Output should be

```
This
is
a
sentence
```

Comment: the OP must use String only

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the split(" ")//which splits the string(maybe a sentence) by spaces into words and use array list to store List words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "));

Comment: Please read carefully. The OP clearly says:  `I can't use arrays.`

Comment: List<String> words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "));

Comment: Definitely still uses an array.

Comment: @littleChild see edit now.//kinda of a fixlike immediately storing into an arraylist

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni yes you are but as a temp.,dunno if thats allowed

Comment: See commentary on the other answers - @Little Child and I are both convinced this is an early in the semester homework...

Answer (score 0):

A raw version, probably efficient, could be something like this. This assumes that there are single spaces between the words including in the end which can easily be tweaked make it perfect.

```
    int wordCount = 0;
    int maxWordLen = 0;
    String longestWord = null;

    if(input != null){//given word
        int currentWordStart = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
            char currentChar = input.charAt(i);
            if(' ' == currentChar){
                wordCount++;
                String currentWord = input.substring(currentWordStart, i);
                int currentWordLen = i - currentWordStart;
                System.out.println("Word: " + currentWord + ", Length: " + currentWordLen);
                currentWordStart = i + 1;
                if(maxWordLen < currentWordLen){
                    maxWordLen = currentWordLen;
                    longestWord = currentWord;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Word count: " + wordCount);
    System.out.println("Longest word: " + longestWord + ", Length: " + maxWordLen);
```